# Multi-Select Two Sides are showing "0 Items" in iPad | iPhone under Aurelia Framework

Tags: ios, ipad, aurelia, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using Aurelia Framework and i use "multiselect-two-sides" in my project .This is working under Microsoft OS ,Chrome and in all browsers but not working properly under iOS platform.

I did many search for fixing this issue because many other users reported this issue.

Recently i used this code to fix my problem but its also not working .

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/i)) {
      $('select[multiple]').each(function () {
        var select = $(this).on({
          "focusout": function () {
            var values = select.val() || [];
            setTimeout(function () {
              select.val(values.length ? values : ['']).change();
            }, 1000);
          }
        });
        var firstOption = '<option value="" disabled="disabled"';
        firstOption += (select.val() || []).length > 0 ? '' : ' selected="selected"';
        firstOption += '>&laquo; Select ' + (select.attr('title') || 'Options') + ' &raquo;';
        firstOption += '</option>';
        select.prepend(firstOption);
      });
    }
```

[image: This is the image under Windows 10 ,Chrome]

[image: This is image under IPhone 6]

[image: This is output result after using above code]

Now i want to fix this in such way that as showing under Windows 10 view .

Comment: Seems more like a bad plugin than an Aurelia issue IMO, the example page is completely broken on both IOS and the new Edge.. Why do you want to use plugin for this? This scenario is trivial to implement in vanilla Aurelia

Comment: is there any other plugin instead of multi-select ?